Defending my PhD thesis in interdisciplinary work (mainly social sciences) in a life sciences college
I am a PhD student in a life sciences college. My PhD project is in collaboration with another research institute specializing in Biomedical ethics and religion. So my PhD work happens to be more of social sciences than life sciences. The thing is I have to defend my PhD thesis in front of the college soon. The audience will be mainly biomedical scientists and students. I am getting the jitters just thinking about this. How do I defend my work in front of such an audience and remove the feeling of inadequacy that I am currently feeling, not to mention the imposter syndrome? Help!!!

The audience is quite likely to be interested in your defense, else they would not show up. And the real audience for the event is your committee - everyone else is there to support you.

Have you gone to other PhD thesis defenses before?

Thank you @JonCuster ..i guess i am afraid of being judged? Or my work not valued? I am not sure.

@Questor Yes i  have attended loads of defenses.. and none of the works were like mine.. guess thats what's contributing to the anxiety
